# How to print value from a lambda function?

Tags: python

Consider the following codes

```
def testfn(x,y):
   yield (x+y)

testt = lambda: testfn(2,3)   
print(testt)
```

Note that here no parameters for lambda function since we have defined a function called testfn with 2 parameters.

The output it shows is

```
<function <lambda> at 0x7ad47f75e320>
```

How to get (print) the value 5 here?

Comment: You need to call the function `testt()`, but also `testfn` is a generator so it won't give you 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps here to get to an output of `5`.

1. `testt` is a function with no parameters: so the syntax to call it is `testt()`. (This is just the same as if you'd defined a function `def testt(): return testfn(2,3)`: there's nothing different about calling it because it was defined using `lambda` instead.)
2. Now, the return value of `testt()` is a generator object, and you want to yield its first value. That can be done with `next()`.

So simply:

```
print(next(testt()))
```

will print `5`.